# Basic eclipse setup for android facebook development

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I am stuck on step 3 of the facebook developers tutorial for setting up eclipse.  Here is step three:

Step-3: Add reference to the Facebook SDK

Create a new Android project for your app or use your existing project and add a reference to the Facebook SDK project. You do this by opening the properties window for our app (File | Properties | Android), pressing the Add... button in the Library area and selecting the Facebook SDK project created above.

When I click add....everything is grayed out and there is nothing to select.  What am I missing?

any help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

download sdk form https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk link

in this you got one project named facebook.

import it in to your eclipse. and then add this facebook project as library of your project from property.

it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you click add it attempts to add what you've already chosen. I believe you have to type in the http link into the "text entry form thingY" and then press add. Or browse, not sure which i don't remember, i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out....I went to help > install new software and installed git.  Then import git and cloned https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git.

From there the step 3 on the facebook android development site worked for me